# Sort array of objects by multiple properties, including objects in nested array

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I know similar questions were asked here multiple times, but something doesn't work there in my case. I have an array of objects with following structure:

```js
const items = [
  {id: 100, title:'text', path: '1', readMessages: [
      {text: 'foo', InsertDate: Moment}
    ], unreadMessages: [
      {text: 'bar', InsertDate: Moment}, {text: 'baz', InsertDate: Moment}
    ]},
  {id: 103, title:'else', path: '1.1', readMessages: [], unreadMessages: [
    {text: 'cux', InsertDate: Moment},
    {text: 'dux', InsertDate: Moment},
    {text: 'tux', InsertDate: Moment}
  ]},
  {id: 110, title:'another', path: '2', readMessages: [], unreadMessages: []}
]
```

I need to make the following sorting to this array:

- Amount of unreadMessages
- Time passed since last message
- path

Important things to take into account: readMessages and unreadMessages arrays may be empty (either one of them or both), InsertDate is a Moment object, path may have'1', '1.1' '1.1.1' structure.

Eventually objects with most unreadMessages should be on top of the list, followed by objects without unreadMessages but with readMessages, and then followed by both arrays empty. All must be sorted first by amount of messages (most of messages first), then by InsertDate (older messages first) and then by path (ascending - 1, 1.1, 1.2, 1.2.1, 1.2.2, 1.3, 2 etc).

I tried to do something like that:

```js
const sortedItems = items.sort((a, b) => {
  if (a.unreadMessages.length === b.unreadMessages.length) {
    if (a.unreadMessages.length) {
      if (a.unreadMessages[a.unreadMessages.length - 1].InsertDate === b.unreadMessages[a.unreadMessages.length - 1].InsertDate) {
        return (a.path < b.path) ? -1 : (a.path > b.path) ? 1 : 0;
      } else {
          return (a.unreadMessages[a.unreadMessages.length - 1].InsertDate < b.unreadMessages[b.unreadMessages.length - 1].InsertDate) ? -1 : 1;
      }
    }
    else if (a.readMessages.length) {
      if (a.readMessages[a.readMessages.length - 1].InsertDate === b.readMessages[a.readMessages.length - 1].InsertDate) {
        return (a.path < b.path) ? -1 : (a.path > b.path) ? 1 : 0;
      } else {
          return (a.unreadMessages[a.unreadMessages.length - 1].InsertDate < b.unreadMessages[b.unreadMessages.length - 1].InsertDate) ? -1 : 1;
      }
    }
  } else {
    return (a.unreadMessages.length < b.unreadMessages.length) ? -1 : 1;
  }
}).reverse()
```

On one hand it does put the objects with most unreadMessages on top, but it does not sort by InsertTime/path. And when I mark one of these questions as read (moving all objects from unreadMessages to readMessages) this objects appears on the very bottom of the list, below objects with both arrays empty.

I thought there might be a problem with sorting by Moment object, so I tried something like `moment(a.readMessages[a.readMessages.length - 1].InsertDate)`, but that didn't help.

Any suggestions, please?

Comment: have you tried creating an array from only `Moment object` and sorting it? and try the same with `path`

Comment: @NikitaMadeev Just tried it with path, seems to be working: https://jsfiddle.net/Igal_K/q7ju1ysv/
Not sure how to try it with Moment objects, but will give it a go.

Comment: @NikitaMadeev Well, tried to reduce the array to get only Moment objects in developer tools console, copied it, for some reason it looks like an array of strings. But the sorting worked: https://jsfiddle.net/Igal_K/oLfnsmdw/3/

Comment: Ok, could you replace in your `items` all `InsertDate` on these strings, use your `sortedItems` and show actual and expected result. This makes it very easy to understand your problem :)

Comment: @NikitaMadeev Sorry, had to be OOO for the rest of the day. I did manage to recreate the code with expected and actual results (see the comments in the code): https://jsfiddle.net/Igal_K/oebqcpnm/39/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const items=[
    {id:100,title:"text",path:"1",readMessages:[{id:1,text:"foo",InsertDate:"2020-07-19T07:14:01.000Z"}],unreadMessages:[{id:5,text:"bar",InsertDate:"2020-07-22T07:03:13.000Z"},{id:6,text:"baz",InsertDate:"2020-07-22T07:03:24.000Z"}]},
    {id:103,title:"else",path:"1.1",readMessages:[],unreadMessages:[{id:3,text:"dux",InsertDate:"2020-07-22T07:02:57.000Z"},{id:4,text:"cux",InsertDate:"2020-07-22T07:03:06.000Z"},{id:2,text:"tux",InsertDate:"2020-07-23T10:35:40.000Z"}]},
    {id:110,title:"another",path:"2",readMessages:[],unreadMessages:[]},
    {id:111,title:"another",path:"3",readMessages:[],unreadMessages:[{id:7,text:"tux",InsertDate:"2020-07-21T10:35:40.000Z"}]},
    {id:112,title:"another",path:"4",readMessages:[],unreadMessages:[{id:8,text:"tux",InsertDate:"2020-07-21T10:35:40.000Z"}]},
    {id:113,title:"another",path:"5",readMessages:[],unreadMessages:[{id:2,text:"tux",InsertDate:"2020-07-20T10:35:40.000Z"},{id:2,text:"lux",InsertDate:"2020-07-21T10:35:40.000Z"}]}
];

const getLastMessage = item => {
    const messages = [...item.readMessages, ...item.unreadMessages].sort((a, b) =>
        a.InsertDate < b.InsertDate ? 1 : -1,
    );

    return messages[0];
};

const sortedItems = items.sort((a, b) => {
    // (1) Amount of unreadMessages [desc]
    if (a.unreadMessages.length > b.unreadMessages.length) {
        return -1;
    } else if (a.unreadMessages.length < b.unreadMessages.length) {
        return 1;
    }

    // (2) Time passed since last message [desc]
    const aLastMessage = getLastMessage(a);
    const bLastMessage = getLastMessage(b);

    // Checking the emptiness of one of the message arrays
    if (aLastMessage && !bLastMessage) {
        return -1;
    } else if (!aLastMessage && bLastMessage) {
        return 1;
    }

    if (aLastMessage.InsertDate > bLastMessage.InsertDate) {
        return -1;
    } else if (aLastMessage.InsertDate < bLastMessage.InsertDate) {
        return 1;
    }

    // (3) Path [asc]
    if (a.path > b.path) {
        return 1;
    } else if (a.path < b.path) {
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
});

console.log(
    'Sorted ids:',
    sortedItems.map(i => i.id),
);
console.log(sortedItems);
```

Comment: Thank you! Looks like exactly what I needed!